# Avro schema is not valid

Tags: amazon-web-services, avro, amazon-personalize

I am trying to save this Avro schema. I get the message that the schema is not valid. Can someone share why its not valid?

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Interactions",
    "namespace": "com.amazonaws.personalize.schema",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "InvoiceNo",
            "type": "int"
        },
        {
            "name": "StockCode",
            "type": "int"
        },
        {
            "name": "Description",
            "type": "long"
        },
        {
            "name": "Quantity",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "InvoiceDate",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "UnitPrice",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "CustomerID",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "CustomerID",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "Country",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ],
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is due to duplicate objects in array `fields`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party here but I think your issue is twofold.

(1) You haven't reformatted your columns to use the field names that Personalize want to see. Required fields for Interactions are USER_ID, ITEM_ID, and TIMESTAMP. (With TIMESTAMP being in Unix Epoch format.) See reference [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/how-it-works-dataset-schema.html).

(2) The five specified fields for Interactions are USER_ID, ITEM_ID, TIMESTAMP, EVENT_TYPE, and EVENT_VALUE. If you do include more fields, they will be considered metadata fields and you can **only include up to 5 metadata fields**. If you do include them AND the data type is "String" you, they must be specified as "categorical". See page 35 of the [Personalize Developer's Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/personalize-dg.pdf) for an example.

Hope this helps!